# How to store multi-layer data in R?

Tags: r, data-structures, hierarchy

I have a dataset of climate model runs. They are currently stored in a list like this:

```
 $ ensemble   :List of 25
  ..$ run_name  :List of 2
  .. ..$ variable: num [1:72, 1:36, 1:12, 1:40] 255 256 256 257 257 ...
```

Where `variable` is a specific model output, like 'surface temperature', with dimensions `[lat, long, month, year]` (don't ask me why the output isn't just by month...)

This is not necessarily the best way to store this data, and I'm wondering if there's an R-ish way of doing it that would make manipulation easier. In particular, I'd like to look at plots of annual averages of each variable for all runs within and ensemble (ie. one plot per ensemble/variable, 25 lines), and statistics for each ensemble over the timeseries (ie. moving PDF), and probably more complex things later.

Ideally I would like to avoid for loops, and use `*apply` functions instead. I have been trying this with this structure, but keep hitting walls like needing to compose two functions within an `lapply()` call, which doesn't work.

Comment: Some reproducible data would be useful, however the function `melt` within the package `reshape2` would appear to be what you are after. This will melt the list to a data frame, which you could use for plotting (using `ggplot2` or otherwise)

Comment: Regarding the use of `*apply` functions. If you `melt` the data, then you will be able to use `ddply` (in `plyr`) to aggregate your data (or you could `data.table` if speed were required).

Comment: if your structures are regular then storing this as an array of dimension (25,2,72,36,12,40) will make life easier.  You can then use plain old `apply` to average across any margins you like, and `melt` as suggested by other comments if you need to generate a long-form version for (e.g.) ggplot2.

Comment: hrm.. @BenBolker, yes, I thought about that, but thought it would be hard to remember the dimensions. But I just realised that you can name array dimensions, and use the names in *apply functions, so that probably is the best option.

Comment: @gavinsimpson: why the name change? This question is specific to R..

Comment: @naught101 That is indicated via the [tag:r] *tag*. If you integrate the "R " bit as one would naturally speak a Question that would be fine. E.g. "How to store multi-layer data in R?". But please don't use it as a tag in the title.

Comment: @BenBolker: unfortunately, I think that doesn't work. I forgot to mention that the ensembles are not all the same size - most are 25, but some are less.

Comment: depending on the degree of irregularity it may still be worth keeping in a regular array with `NA` values in appropriate places -- then e.g. `apply(myarray,MARGIN=...,mean,na.rm=TRUE)` will still give you the appropriate averages